# Is it possible to use Nuxt.js + Vuetify + external Javascript library?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs

I am using Nuxt.js with Vuetify, I would like to use an external Javascript library only for the menu, but **it seems that the 2 do not want to coexist** because I do not see any event coming from the external Javascript library being assigned to an HTML element.

Is the idea of wanting to make Vuetify coexist with an external bookstore possible or not?

Did I forget something in the Webpack configuration? Can you help me?

Here is my `nuxt.config.js`

```js
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

const webpack = require("webpack")

export default {
  /*
  ** Nuxt rendering mode
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode
  */
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Nuxt target
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-target
  */
  target: 'server',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head
  */
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - ' + process.env.npm_package_name,
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    script: [
      { src: 'https://botifulthemes.net/js/jquery/jquery.js' },
      { src: 'https://botifulthemes.net/js/vendor.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'https://botifulthemes.net/js/underscore.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'https://botifulthemes.net/js/app.min.js', body: true }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [

  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  ** https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins
  */
  plugins: [
    // { src: '~plugins/vendor-app.js' },
    // { src: '~plugins/underscore-app.js' },
    // { src: '~plugins/main-app.js' },
  ],
  /*
  ** Auto import components
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-components
  */
  components: true,
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {},
  /*
  ** vuetify module configuration
  ** https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module
  */
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      options: {
        customProperties: true
      },
      dark: false,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        },
        light: {
          background: '#001429',
          primary: '#f4511e',
          secondary: '#001429'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/
  */
  build: {
    // vendor: [ 'jquery' ],
    // plugins: [
    //     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    //         $: 'jquery',
    //         jQuery: 'jquery',
    //         'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    //     })
    // ],
    /*
    ** Vous pouvez étendre la configuration webpack ici
   */
   extend(config, ctx) {
      // Exécuter ESLint lors de la sauvegarde
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: "pre",
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: "eslint-loader",
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          options: {
            fix: true
          }
        })
        // config.module.rules.push({
        //     test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
        //     loader: 'file-loader',
        //     options: {
        //       name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        //     }
        // })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is this part below that is not active :

```js
script: [
      { src: 'https://botifulthemes.net/js/jquery/jquery.js' },
      { src: 'https://botifulthemes.net/js/vendor.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'https://botifulthemes.net/js/underscore.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'https://botifulthemes.net/js/app.min.js', body: true }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

As in this document said "Vue is a jealous library in the sense that you must let it completely own the patch of DOM that you give it (defined by what you pass to el)"

SO if you want to use other library like jquery read link below would be useful
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/